# is it possible to put iframe value in textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have seen in some websites, such as Wordpress, that they have rich text editors with a toggle option with which you can see html code of what you are typing. Is there any way I can see the src of an iframe in a textarea?

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
<iframe name="editor"style="width:600px;height:500px"id="iframe"></iframe>
<input type ="button"id="btn"value="btn"/>

<script>
       editor.document.designMode='on';
       $("#btn").click(function(){
               $("#textarea").val($("#iframe").val());
       })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an ajax [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) request

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var iframe_url = $("#iframe").attr('src');

    $("#textarea").val( 'loading...' );

    $.get( iframe_url, {}, function(response){
        $("#textarea").val( response );
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if your `iframe`'s content comes from the same server as does the HTML outside the `iframe`. If this is the case, then:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('html').html();
```

should work. If it's not the case, then it's impossible to do this. There's more info on the reason for this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).